# Recycling a parent ViewController's UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

My ViewController creates 60 little UIViews. Each one requires a UIImage of the same jpg  (to use in a UIImageView).

My theory is that instead of each UIView creating its own UIImage, it would be better to reuse one UIImage, defined in the ViewController.

ViewController code:

```
UIImage *reuseableUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LittlePicture.jpg"];

for (i=0; i<60; i++){
    [arrayOfUIViews addObject:[[myUIViewMaker alloc] init...]];
}
```

Is my theory wrong? Should I just go ahead and create the UIImage in each UIView?

If my theory is good, **how can my UIViews target the parent ViewController's UIImage?**
I don't know the syntax. To illustrate (badly), the code inside the UIView would be *something like* this:

```
finalUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.parentViewController.reuseableUIImage];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok and should work correctly.  You would need to define a property on your viewController to hold the UIImage.

The main benefit you will get from this is that the time to load the image will only happen once.  If you alloc and init an image for each view it will have to load the image each time.

EDIT:

Thinking about it again, the best way would be to pass the image into your child view when you init it.

```
UIImage *reuseableUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LittlePicture.jpg"];

for (i=0; i<60; i++){
    [arrayOfUIViews addObject:[[myUIViewMaker alloc] initWithImage:reusableUIImage]];
}
```

Your init method in your myUIViewMaker class would be implemented as:

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        finalUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];  
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Pleased to hear my theory is correct! But the syntax definitely is not. I need to know how to targer the (parent) ViewController and its UIImage. Do you know how? Would appreciate it if you could show me.

Comment: (I have now defined and @synthasized the UIImage property in the ViewController.)

Comment: please see my edit, i think this would be a better way to handle it

Comment: I did think about that passing idea - but wouldn't that simply be duplicating another UIImage?  - Or is it passing a reference to the one UIImage?

Comment: its just passing the reference into the child view

Comment: With 1,180 points to date, I'll trust you! Thanks for your help Craig.